# Pentaho Report Use parameter in host name in JDBC Data Source

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I created a report shown in Pentaho Dashboard.
The Dashboard is implemented on many machines.
So, I must edit JDBC DataSouce in all SubReports in my report to match the hostname to introduce environment. (I am using `MySQL`)

Can I use a parameter in the hostname in DataSource ex. `${HostName}`?

I tried to do that, but then the value wasn't shown in `DataSet` when I clicked `DataSource` and clicked `SelectQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
I make report in Pentaho Report Designer with JNDI connection.
I published its report to my BI Server.

I edited these two files.

\biserver-ce\tomcat\conf\context.xml

\biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\web.xml

Then the report showed data in datasource in context.xml.